# How to Click a Span Without a Name or ID

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to use Pupeteer to respond to a popup dialog box, but can't find a way to click the OK button which is just an image inside a `<span>`

This is what I've tried so far:

```
  const [button] = await frame.$x('/html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/span[1]');
  
  if (button) {
       await button.click()
  }
```

But the button is not found.

This is the pertinent section of the html:

```
   <div class="vtm_text vtm_exportDialog"><input type="hidden" value="save">
      ...
      <span class="vtmBtn" style="min-width: 60px; padding: 3px;">OK</span>
      <span class="vtmBtn" style="min-width: 60px; padding: 3px;">Cancel</span>
    </div>
```

This is what the page looks like when inspected in Chrome:

[image: This is what the page looks like when inspected in Chrome]

Comment: Can you show the actual page and a [mcve]? The tiny HTML snippet here doesn't necessarily capture all of the things that might cause it not to work and there's no way to verify it against your code or provide a runnable, guaranteed working solution for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using $eval as follows:

```
await frame.$eval('span[class=vtmBtn]', el => el.click());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const [button] = await frame.$x("/html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/span[1]");

async function pop_up() {
  if (button) {
    await button.click();
  }
}

document.getElementsByClassName("vtmBtn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("src", "");
  //   in the empty string put the path of the image you want

  e.target.appendChild(img);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. Can you describe what your solution does in more detail? I guess I would call the function `pop_up()`. What does `appendChild` do?

Comment: @Ahmed Welcome to SO! Please use 4 spaces or triple backticks to indent your code. We have an autoformatter in stack snippets. It's possible to [edit] your post once you post it and see something is wrong (or use the preview). Also, a bit of language to accompany the code is great if you don't mind walking us through it. Thanks!